# jsPDF error in NativeScript: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: window

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nativescript, jspdf

I am trying to add jsPDF in my NativeScript project (Angular + Typescript) to convert HTML to PDF. I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@kumarandena/pdf-generation-in-nativescript-using-javascript-libraries-864ecf4e9a3a) on how to use jsPDF in NativeScript. However I keep running into the same error when I try to code the example:

```
let doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.setFontSize(26);
        doc.text(40, 40, "First PDF with NativeScript using jsPDF!");
        let dataUrl = doc.output('datauristring');
        if(dataUrl) {
            dialogs.alert({
                title: "jsPDF - Base64",
                message: dataUrl,
                okButtonText: "Copy to Clipboard"
            }).then(() => {
                clipboard.setText(dataUrl)
            });
        }
```

I keep getting following error:

> NativeScript encountered a fatal error: ReferenceError: Can't find
>   variable: window

I thought these lines would take care of this error but they don't, I tried to add this in the component I was trying to use the pdf generation and also in the main.ts and in the app.component.ts:

```
global['window'] = {
    'document': {
        'createElementNS': () => { return {} }
    }
};
global['document'] = {
    'createElement': (str) => { return {} }
};
global['navigator'] = {};
//Imports
var base64 = require('base-64');
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
global['btoa'] = (str) => {
    return base64.encode(str);
};
global['atob'] = (bytes) => {
    return base64.decode(bytes);
};
global['u8'] = {};
```

However I keep getting the same error and can't find any differences between my code and the [working example playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=OGrw9s&v=8&_ga=2.202298769.1418875902.1570200843-1896458786.1567691562). I also added all libraries and the plugin that was needed to make this example work:

```
npm install jspdf --save
npm install @types/jspdf --save
npm install base-64 --save
npm install utf8 --save
tns plugin add nativescript-clipboard
```

**EDIT** I also tried to downgrade these node modules to the exact same version that the playground was using. Still same error.

**EDIT** If I use the node modules the same way as in the playground, so I am just adding them to the app directory, it works as it is supposed too. Still this feels as a bad work around, is there another solution?

Does someone see what I am doing wrong or what I am missing here? Any help would be really nice, thanks in advance!

Comment: You could download the Playground demo and compare the project locally to see what is missing on your side - I've just started the demo locally and it works as expected.

Comment: That is exactly what I did I compared everything, however it doesn't make it work for me.